# How long does it take to "save artifacts" to Ropsten?

Tags: truffle, ropsten, truffle-migration

Migrating contracts with Truffle I get stuck at

```
Saving artifacts...
```

Sometimes for 10 minutes or more.

I also get:

```
Error: Transaction 0x123...123 wasn't processed in 240 seconds!
```

Is it normal that test network is so slow?

Comment: My "truffle migrate" stuck at "Deploying migrations". Etherscan shows that two contracts are created but still in "pending" state even after 25 minutes

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem which seems to be persistent. It seems to be HD wallet provider related. Anyways, my contracts have been successfully deployed and status is **SUCCESS**, so no problems with using them. You can follow these threads or answer first :
 1. https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-migrate/issues/14
 2. https://github.com/rhlsthrm/truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey/issues/3